# IN ORACLE - EMPTYCLOB should display as empty field in the SELECT Query

Tags: sql, database, oracle

In filetable there are few empty clob in MYFILE column and I need to select all the columns but if there is no empty CLOB I need to show the Download, in case of emptyclob it should not show anything
but for emptyclob also I am getting Download. Is there any way to show empty_clob with '' and if the clob is not empty then only show Download

```
SELECT nvl2(MYFILE,'Download','') as downloadFile, filename  from filetable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to test the length of the CLOB

```
select filename
       , case when length(myfile)>0 the 'Download' else '' end downloadfile
from filetable
;
```